# lm function error on RenjinScriptEngine (EvalException)

Tags: java, r, renjin

I found when all values are the same, the lm function throws errors. But it worked on GNU R. I am using the latest `renjin-script-engine-0.8.1593.jar`.

Any exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.renjin.eval.EvalException: contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
    at org.renjin.primitives.Conditions.stop(Conditions.java:193)
    at org.renjin.primitives.R$primitive$stop.doApply(R$primitive$stop.java:72)"
```

when I called RenjinScriptEngine.eval(..) with this script:

```
fit<-lm("formula"=vals~index,"data"=data)
```

The data of input is

```
"2015-36",9
"2015-37",9
"2015-41",9.
```

Answer (score 0):

Renjin's goal is to be compatible with the latest version of GNU R. If you find a difference or encounter error like that above, please file a bug report at https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues. We're happy to have the test cases!